# Why create method does not return object with id?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following table TodoList :

```
class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and

```
class CreateTodoLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :todo_lists do |t|
      t.string :list_name
      t.date :list_due_date
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I create crud methods:

```
  def create_todolist(params)
      todolist = TodoList.create(list_name:params[:name], list_due_date: params[:due_date])
  end
```

And i have the followging tests:

```
     context "the code has to create_todolist method" do
        it { is_expected.to respond_to(:create_todolist) } 
        it "should create_todolist with provided parameters" do
            expect(TodoList.find_by list_name: "mylist").to be_nil
            due_date=Date.today
            assignment.create_todolist(:name=> 'mylist', :due_date=>due_date)
            testList = TodoList.find_by list_name: 'mylist'
            expect(testList.id).not_to be_nil
            expect(testList.list_name).to eq "mylist"
            expect(testList.list_due_date).to eq due_date
            expect(testList.created_at).not_to be_nil
            expect(testList.updated_at).not_to be_nil
        end  

  end
```

When i launch the test give me the following errors:

```
       Assignment rq03 rq03.2 assignment code has create_todolist method should create_todolist with provided parameters: 
Failure/Error: 
expect(testList.id).not_to be_nil NoMethodError: undefined method id' for nil:NilClass 
# ./spec/assignment_spec.rb:173:in block (4 levels) in <top (required)>' 
# ./spec/assignment_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is are my  project directories: 
 [image]

It seems that the create method was not successful. What is the problem please ?

Comment: I think there might be an unnecessary  `:` in ` TodoList.find_by list_name: 'mylist'`

Comment: @pracede Could you show code of `TodoList` model?

Comment: @MaximPontyushenko i add the TodoList model

Comment: @pracede Are you able to create object with `create_todolist` from console?

Comment: @RubyRacer The error appears on id. not on TodoList.find_by list_name

Comment: @pracede and where is `create_todolist` method defined?

Comment: @MaximPontyushenko create_todolist is defined in assignment directory

Comment: Change `create` to `create!` to see what the error is.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth i change and still have the same error

Comment: why not change to this `testList = assignment.create_todolist(:name=> 'mylist', :due_date=>due_date)` rather than query the database again? BTW lowerCamelCase is not ruby style use snake_case instead.

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from the following lines of code:

```
    assignment.create_todolist(:name=> 'mylist', :due_date=>due_date)
    testList = TodoList.find_by list_name: 'mylist'
    expect(testList.id).not_to be_nil
```

In the first line, you're trying to create a record. But you don't actually check if the model is successfully saved or not. If the model could not be saved, your `find_by` call will return nil. Then when you call `testList.id`, you're essentially calling the `id` method on a nil object, resulting in your error.

You should put a breakpoint in your test and run the lines one-by-one manually to inspect the result. Useful active record methods are `valid?`, `persisted?` and `errors.full_messages`. Things are easier to debug this way.

You should also practice reading errors, as there's a lot of information you can learn from them. To take your error, for example:

```
expect(testList.id).not_to be_nil NoMethodError: undefined method id' for nil:NilClass 
# ./spec/assignment_spec.rb:173:in block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So here you can see that the error is occurring on line 173 in assignment_spec.rb. `undefined method id for nil:NilClass` tells you that you're trying to call `id` on a nil object. Knowing that `find_by` can produce nil objects, I felt like I had located the problem. I'm repeating myself here, but this is just an example of how I'm thinking through a debugging problem.